# count with load Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Is it possible to count inside load

I have situation like this:

```
$offer->load([
           'coupons', 'coupons.couponItems' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name');
        }, 'coupons.userCoupons' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'coupon_id');
        },
    ]);
```

I want to count `userCoupons`

If not, what is the best solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a `->loadCount()` after your load call. Unfortunately, Laravel doesn't support dot notation at that point due to complexity, so `->loadCount('coupons.userCoupons')` will not work.

You can add a `HasManyThrough` relationship on your Offer model, however, for instance

```php
    public function UserCoupons(): HasManyThrough
    {
       return $this->hasManyThrough(UserCoupon::class, Coupon::class);
    }
```

You can then just do a `$offer->loadCount('UserCoupons')`.